# Chartkick Pie chart not showing percentages when using library options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, charts, chartkick

In my ROR I want to add Percentages to my Piechart, I'm using the `chartkick` gem to render the Pie chart. I've tried various approaches to the problem, but none seems to work. I've also googled around and look at similar posts at stack overflow.

This is what I've come up with but it's not showing the %.

```
 <%= pie_chart [["Soccer", @soccer_total], ["Basketball",  @basketball_total, ["Baseball",  @baseball_total], ["Other", @other_total ]], library: {legend: {labelFormat: '{name} : {y} ({percentage}%)'}} %>
```

I've also tried this approach, but still with out a luck

```
<%= pie_chart [["Soccer", @soccer_total], ["Basketball",  @basketball_total, ["Baseball",  @baseball_total], ["Other", @other_total ]], library: {pieSliceText: 'value-and-percentage'} %>
```

Please can someone more experienced help me with this?

**UPADATE FOR OSCAR'S ANSWER**

I followed the directions provided for Oscar's answer but its still not showing %.

This how the `<head>`in  `application.html.erb` looks:

```
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "path/to/highcharts.js", "chartkick" %>
```

and the `appplication.js` is like this:

```
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: By getting rid of Chart.bundle in application.js shows the percentage in pie chart

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem working with this. So `Chart.bundle` doesn't provide that options for pie chart

Instead of that you can use Google Charts as specified at documentation [here](https://github.com/ankane/chartkick#google-charts)

So what you have to do is remove `//= require Chart.bundle` from application.js

Go to application.html.erb or the layout that you are using for showing your view and before `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>` or something similar that you have for loading js libs add `<%= javascript_include_tag "https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js" %>`. It will look like this:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

And there is!. Also I noticed that you are missing a "]" at your code. Fixing that you can run the chart with this:

```
<%= pie_chart [["Soccer", @soccer_total], ["Basketball",  @basketball_total], ["Baseball",  @baseball_total], ["Other", @other_total ]] %>
```

You should be able to see the percentages without adding any options

If you want customize the chart options then you can see the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery)

EDIT: You `application.js` should look like this

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require chartkick
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

And your `application.html.erb or the layout that you are using at your controller like` this(delete that highcharts.js include_tag at the end you don't need it):

```
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

Comment: Thank you @Oscar Luza, I  tried to modify the files according to your answer, but it is still not showing the % in the chart.  Please see my edit to the Question.

Comment: at you application.js you are missing this `//= require chartkick`

Comment: @Slowboy  only remove `//= require Chart.bundle` not the other line, take a look at the edit

Comment: if I remove the `include_tag`for `highcharts.js` my graphs are displaying this messages `Error Loading Chart: No adapter found`

Comment: @Slowboy Did you copy and paste the code at `application.js` and on your layout `application.html.erb`?. That error means that you are not loading this line `  <%= javascript_include_tag "https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js" %>`at `application.html.erb`. In other case it can be that you are using another layout at your controller for rendering the views where the charts are

Answer (score 4):

hey You can find Something better [here](https://richonrails.com/articles/charting-with-chartkick)

As per my opinion, you can try this code.
Instead of this

```
<%= pie_chart [["Soccer", @soccer_total], ["Basketball",  @basketball_total, ["Baseball",  @baseball_total], ["Other", @other_total ]], library: {pieSliceText: 'value-and-percentage'} %>
```

You can Try This

```
<%= pie_chart [["Soccer", @soccer_total], ["Basketball",  @basketball_total, ["Baseball",  @baseball_total], ["Other", @other_total ]], library: {pieSliceText: 'value'} %>
```

**Hey you can puth below code in your header.**

```
<script> https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.0/Chart.bundle.js</script>
<script> https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.0/Chart.bundle.min.js</script>
<script> https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.0/Chart.js</script>
<script> https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.0/Chart.min.js</script>
```

Comment: Thank you @Ronak Bhatt  but your solution isn't changing anything, still can't see the percentage

Answer (score 1):

I made it by doing this

1) I configured my Chartkick to use Highcharts, as described in https://github.com/ankane/chartkick.

2) I used the following library options with my pie chart:

```
library: {plotOptions: {pie: {dataLabels: {format: "<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.y} ({point.percentage:.1f}%)"}}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

ChartKick now supports the feature.
You can use

```
<%= pie_chart data, suffix: "%" %>
```